# How to add image name to docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file that I use the `image` block in the service to name. For example

```
version: '3'

services:

  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "6379"

  worker:
    image: worker:production
    build: .
    user: root
    command: celery -A ExactEstate worker --loglevel=info
    env_file: ./.env.prod
    restart: unless-stopped
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis

  beats:
    image: beats:production
    build: .
    user: root
    command: celery --pidfile= -A ExactEstate beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
    env_file: ./.env.prod
    restart: unless-stopped
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
  web:
    image: web:production
    build: .
    user: root
    command: daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 ExactEstate.asgi:application
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file: ./.env.prod
    restart: unless-stopped
    links:
      - redis
      - worker
      - beats
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - worker
      - beats
```

This gives a `docker ps` of:

```
0ad78269a9ce        beats:production       "celery --pidfile= -…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes                                  exactestate_beats_1
1a44f7c98b50        worker:production      "celery -A ExactEsta…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes                                  exactestate_worker_1
f3a09723ba66        redis               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:32769->6379/tcp   exactestate_redis_1
```

Let's suppose I also have built containers from a different compose file (i.e. staging) How can I use docker-compose to on pull up the exact service/image I want?

For example: `docker-compose up web:production` or `docker-compose up web:staging`

Comment: Can you describe a little bit more how these setups are different?  You can use [environment variable expansion](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution) to specify the exact `image:` value at startup time, but you can't necessarily use `docker-compose up` to start some other Compose setup's services in the current context.  (Typical best practice is to use the same image in all environments, if that helps your setup -- your staging environment should be running the exact same image you're going to promote to production.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I cannot use the same Dockerfile for staging and production as part of the file is `RUN npm install --only=production && npm run build:staging`... My npm builds are different and my static files for staging and production are in different locations

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using environment variables. Variables for `docker-compose up` could be passed as `.env` file or set by `export` (or `set` on Windows) command ([docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)).

```
  web:
    image: web:production
```

Should be changed to

```
  web:
    image: web:${ENV}
```

And then you can run your application by running

```
$ export ENV=production && docker-compose up
```

Or you can create `.env` file containing line `ENV=production`. Then you can simply run application with `docker-compose up`.